# Is there a way to add all items in an Amazon wish list to your cart?

Tags: amazon, wish-list

For example I created a wish list of the books needed for my fall classes.

Is there a one click (or other short/easy) way to add all the items into my cart other than clicking on "Add to Cart" for each individual item?

Comment: Is there a way to do the opposite?  My shopping cart is completely full (the "buy later" bin) over years of moving things and accumulating products I like.  I'd like to transfer these ALL to a wishlist, but clicking on each individual product and selecting a wishlist could take hours.  I need to have a script do this all-at-once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to do this other than by scripting.

This seems like a good suggestion to put to Amazon though.

Comment: 6 years and this feature still doesn't exist?

Comment: 7 years and this feature still doesn't exist...

Comment: 8 years and this feature still doesn't exist...?

Comment: 9 years and this feature still doesn't exist...

Comment: 10 years and this feature still doesn't exist...?

Comment: 11 Years and this feature still doesn't exist.........

Comment: 12 Years and this feature still doesn't exist....?

Comment: 13 years and this feature still doesn't exist...?

Comment: 14 years and this feature still doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-action=reg-item-inline-order]'), function(e) { setTimeout(function() { e.click() }, 100) })
```

The selector may have to change in the future, but this worked for me.

Comment: yeah currently the value for `data-action` is `add-to-car'. `data-add-to-cart` has the item's metadata in it, which is super useful (you can parse price and stuff out of the string).

Comment: @cowbert you could have edited the answer...

Comment: This no longer works, and it didn't work. Note that some of the main yellow buttons on list items are, for me, 'Buy now with 1-click' instead of 'Add to Cart'.

I also tried this and it didn't work (it seemed to push one button and took me to another page): `Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[role=button]'), function(e) { if(e.innerHTML.trim()=="Add to Cart") { setTimeout(function() { e.click() }, 100) } })`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I ran into the same issue a few days ago. Made a thing that helps as browser extension. Try it out, let me know your thoughts? Thanks! https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wishlist-to-cart-for-amaz/hcidhephpgibbomfkllaaebnlokpemim?hl=en-US